# Exception: Server was unable to process request. ---> Data is Null

Tags: c#, web-services, exception, vsto

Here is the detailed Exception thrown by the following line of code which calls a web method

```
string[] results = webservice.getResultsArray(strUser, inputArray);
```

> **Server was unable to process request. ---> Data is Null. This method
>   or property cannot be called on Null values.**
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)

I have actually put checks before calling `getResultsArray` web method, which goes

```
if(strUser!=null && inputArray !=null)
    string[] results = webservice.getResultsArray(strUser, inputArray);
```

to make sure that the passing parameters are not null in the first place.

But it still doesn't seem to solve the issue and continues to throw the same exception, which really gives me a headache.

Has anyone ever experienced this issue before? Any insight or suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This was the explanation on one of MS forums.

What happened is the specific method you are calling is causing an exception to be thrown.

Do you have proper error handling on the WCF service to either return faults or return a fault contract?

Do you have logging/tracing on your code so you can see what is happening?

Have a look at the event log to see if your WCF service is throwing any errors

http://forums.asp.net/t/1659885.aspx/1

=============================

This is another post from previous SO.

I have no idea what causes this so this is not an answer to your question, but only a suggestion for a way to look further into the problem

Try using a sniffer to look at the actual data being sent between the machines and find out on which side the problem is. I've used Wireshark successfully once.

[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ArgumentNullException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563162/system-web-services-protocols-soapexception-server-was-unable-to-process-request)